# How to rotate my application 180 degree upside down upon rotating device 180 degree upside down?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have developed one application and configured its orientation is Landscape so it will always display on landscape view on the device.

Now i want to rotate it 180 degree upside down when user rotate the device 180 degree upside down so it will adjust accordingly and displays to the user properly.At present if I am rotating device 180 degree upside down, My application doesn't adjust accordingly as per the rotation so it will display in reverse (from bottom to top) for example: suppose my activity is having 2 text fields on the top and 2 buttons on the bottom so if you rotate device 180 degree upside down, Activity is not adjusting accordingly, so user can see buttons on the top and text fields are on bottom which is wrong it should adjust/rotate as per the device rotation and must display text fields on the top and buttons on bottom.

Please provide your valuable solutions to resolve this problem.

Regards,
Piks

Comment: hei,,i actually want the opposite of your question,,i dont want it to flip 180. How did u do it,,,

Answer (score 21):

specify:

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. This will transform application between landscape and reverseLandscape.

Comment: After going through 10-12 answers and after spending 2-3 hours, this answer solved my problem in a second.

Comment: Thanks man, this solved my problem.This should be accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, you need to configure the `<activity>` to use the orientation from the sensor. This should be the default, but you can force it to the sensor's orientations, for all 4 possible orientations, with `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"`. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

EDIT: If you want to enable all but one orientation, you could disable that orientation by intercepting the orientation change event and quashing it in your `Activity`:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
  if (config.orientation != Activity.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    setRequestedOrientation(config.orientation);
  {
}
```

(This is off the top of my head but think it works, or something nearly like it.)

You need to tell Android to let the app handle orientation changes too in your `<activity>` with `android:configChanges="orientation"`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs but it seems like not supported in android 2.1 api level 7.is there any way to support in 2.1 api level 7? And i don't want to rotate my app in portrait mode so i need to fix the orientation of app is Landscape but it should allow me to rotate 180 degree upside down.

Comment: "sensor" works too but may not allow reverse-landscape orientation on some devices. I'll edit my answer with a way to exclude one orientation.

Comment: above code is not working as expected, after rotating device 180 degree, activity doesn't redraw itself to display as per device rotation.