# Android rotation in 4 direction

Tags: android, android-orientation

I know the rotation of mobile in 180 degree is not possible (With back button on top side) but I want a official link of explanation for this.

So does any one has a official link or anything that will explain this?

Thank You

Note:-- I don't want to explicitly set orientation to reverse portrait but when user rotate the application it should go in reverse portrait mode....

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this kind of rotation is possible.

To achieve this, just add this line for your activity in Manifest.xml

```
android:screenOrientation="reversePortrait"
```

P.S. [Note](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen), that this feature was added only in API Level 9.

Answer (score 0):

The 180 degree rotation is possible: Check this link:

[How to rotate my application 180 degree upside down upon rotating device 180 degree upside down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987578/how-to-rotate-my-application-180-degree-upside-down-upon-rotating-device-180-deg)

Hope this will help.